# ng if with angular for string contains

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, arrays, angularjs

I have the following Angular code:

```
<li ng-repeat="select in Items">   
         <foo ng-repeat="newin select.values">
{{new.label}}</foo>
```

How can I use an ng-if condition to look for a specific character:

```
ng-if="select.name == '?'"
```

to only display the code when the character is here? The value I have is like 88?77 and the numbers are dynamic but the question mark is always there, I can't seem to filter based on that?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

**ES2015 UPDATE**

ES2015 have [`String#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) method that checks whether a string contains another. This can be used if the target environment supports it. The method returns `true` if the *needle* is found in *haystack* else returns `false`.

```
ng-if="haystack.includes(needle)"
```

Here, `needle` is the string that is to be searched in `haystack`.

See [**Browser Compatibility**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#Browser_compatibility) table from MDN. Note that this is not supported by IE and Opera. In this case [**polyfill**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#Polyfill) can be used.

---

You can use [`String#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) to get the index of the *needle* in *haystack*.

1. If the *needle* is not present in the *haystack* **-1** is returned.
2. If *needle* is present at the beginning of the *haystack* **0** is returned.
3. Else the index at which *needle* is, is returned.

The index can be compared with `-1` to check whether *needle* is found in *haystack*.

```
ng-if="haystack.indexOf(needle) > -1"
```

---

**For Angular(2+)**

```
*ngIf="haystack.includes(needle)"
```

Comment: *ngIf="haystack.includes(needle)" for Angular 2+

Answer (score 11):

```
ng-if="select.name.indexOf('?') !== -1"
```

Answer (score 9):

All javascript methods are applicable with angularjs because angularjs itself is a javascript framework so you can use indexOf() inside angular directives

```
<li ng-repeat="select in Items">   
         <foo ng-repeat="newin select.values">
<span ng-if="newin.label.indexOf(x) !== -1">{{newin.label}}</span></foo>
</li>
//where x is your character to be found
```

Answer (score 1):

Only the shortcut syntax worked for me ***ngIf**.

(I think it's the later versions that use this syntax if I'm not mistaken)

```
<div *ngIf="haystack.indexOf('needle') > -1">
</div>
```

or

```
<div *ngIf="haystack.includes('needle')">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

### In Angular2 you should consider using a (pure) pipe for this

You could consider adding your own custom "includes" pipe:

```typescript
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'includes',
})
export class Includes implements PipeTransform {

  public transform(haystack: string, needle: string): boolean;
  public transform<T>(array: T[], item: T): boolean;
  public transform(haystack: any[]|string, needle: any|string): boolean {
    return haystack.includes(needle);
  }
}
```

This pipe would work both for finding items in an array or string in string searches.

You can use this pipe in the template as follows:

```
<div *ngIf="haystack | includes : needle">
  //...
<div>
```

---

**Note:** *This seems like a lot of overhead since you could just do like suggested in the other answers:*

```
<div *ngIf="haystack.includes(needle)">
  //...
</div>
```

*But when using such a solution the `includes` mehtod will be called on each change detection, even in cases where the value of `haystack` didn't change. By using a pipe you will make sure it will only be executed when `haystack` has changed. 

See for more information on this topic [the official Angular documentation on pure pipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#detecting-pure-changes-to-primitives-and-object-references).*

Answer (score 0):

Do checks like that in a controller function. Your HTML should be easy-to-read markup without logic.

Controller:

```
angular.module("myApp")
.controller("myController",function(){
    var self = this;

    self.select = { /* ... */ };

    self.showFoo = function() {
        //Checks if self.select.name contains the character '?'
        return self.select.name.indexOf('?') != -1;
    }
});
```

Page example:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController as vm">
    <p ng-show="vm.showFoo()">Bar</p>
</div>
```