# How i can do it in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i need get these behavior

```
ng-if='season in current_user.subscriptions'
```

It is necessary to check the availability of the season in the user's subscriptions , the subscription comes array.How i can i do that?

My data for current_user:
[image]
and for season

[image]
I want to show the item when the array user subscriptions present this season

Comment: what is the question? It is very unclear what you are asking

Comment: Please clarify your question. It's really hard to tell what you're actually trying to accomplish here.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30869370/ng-if-with-angular-for-string-contains

Comment: I want to show the item when the array user subscriptions present this season

Comment: @danii
I want to show the item when the array user subscriptions present this season

Comment: stop posting pictures of code!

Comment: @iliacholy its data from console, i cant post it pretty from console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd make a predicate function for it.

```
ng-if="hasSubscription(season)"
```

define it in your controller or directive:

```
$scope.hasSubscription = function (sub) {
  var i, subs = $scope.current_user.subscriptions;
  for (i = 0; i < subs.length; i++) {
    if (subs[i].id === sub.id) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
};
```

Comment: i add some data, сheck it please

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
ng-if="current_user.subscriptions.indexOf(season) != -1"
```

This directive will render the element **only** if the `season` is included inside the array `current_user.subscriptions`. Please do check all necessary values are available in the `$scope`.

Comment: i add some data, сheck it please

Answer (score 0):

you can verify the length of the subscription like ... ng-if="current_user.subscriptions.season"