# Angular see if String is Within Another String, using Substring and ngIf

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular8

I am doing the following, trying to check if addressDescription contains the word Maple street.
Receiving the following error, how would this be fixed?

```
<app-address-mailing *ngIf="message.addressDescription.indexOf('Maple') > -1"></app-address-mailing>
```

> AddressMailingComponent.html:21 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

Resource below was not working, plus its older, new syntax is `ngIf`  not `ng-if`

[ng if with angular for string contains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30869370/ng-if-with-angular-for-string-contains)

Comment: try `*ngIf="message.addressDescription?.indexOf('Maple')` with a nullable operator

Comment: hi @terahertz hmm, that get rids of compilation error, now its rendering the html item, even if Maple does not exist, I just tried <app-address-mailing *ngIf="message.addressDescription.indexOf('randomwordrandomwordrrandomword') > -1"></app-address-mailing>  , and displays without really checking if statement, strange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error suggests:

`message.addressDescription` is undefined.

So you can add a new condition:

```
*ngIf="message?.addressDescription && message.addressDescription.indexOf('Maple') > -1"
```

With this condition, you will be sure that it's valid.

Answer (score 0):

**message is not defined**, first check then use `includes`

if `addressDescription` is a sentence,  try the following

```
<app-address-mailing *ngIf="message?.addressDescription.split(' ').includes('Maple')"></app-address-mailing>
```

otherwise, try the following

```
<app-address-mailing *ngIf="message?.addressDescription.includes('Maple')"></app-address-mailing>
```

Needless to say : you can apply `toLowerCase` method.